# Programmatically stop and start daemon

Tags: ios7, xcode5, daemon, jailbreak

I want to stop my daemon from inside it. In other words daemon should stop and restart itself when a specific event occur. I am using following command it works fine in terminal but not inside daemon.

```
system("launchctl stop com.test.myDaemon");
```

Comment: You want to restart it (stop and start immediately)? Or you want to stop it, wait a bit for a specific event and then launch it again? Those are very different cases.

Comment: I just want to stop and restart it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest way of doing it.

In your daemon plist file add this

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
```

That way iOS will automatically restart your daemon when it quits for whatever reason (signal, exception, daemon itself).

When you need to restart your daemon simply call

```
exit(0);
```

Comment: Its not restarting my Daemon where I have **KeepAlive** key in plist file.

Comment: You should definitely look at Nate's answer. Both my solution and your's `launchctl stop com.test.myDaemon` coupled with KeepAlive should work. If they don't it means there is probably something wrong with your daemon.

Comment: Thanks it works for me now. The problem was that exit code was called enough times as Nate described in step 4

Comment: How you fixed it? I guess random non-zero exit code could work.

Answer (score 2):

[creker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24696312/119114) worked for me on a jailbroken iOS 7.0.4 phone.  However, you should be able to make your `launchctl` work as well (yes, I tested this, too).

Here are some things you might want to check:

1. Are you doing something in your daemon's plist file that changes which user it runs as?  If you are telling launchd to run your daemon as a non-root user, that might prevent your programmatic launchctl command from working.
2. Do you have an entry in your plist file for the `OnDemand` key?  Normally, you shouldn't.  I'm wondering if you do, and it's conflicting with the `KeepAlive` setting in creker's answer.
3. Are you sure that this command **exactly** (`launchctl stop com.test.myDaemon`) succeeds from the command line?

The reason I ask is that many people build their Launch Daemons based on [a tutorial here](https://www.chrisalvares.com/blog/38/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-4/).  In general, it's a great tutorial.  But, there is at least one mistake.  In the sample daemon .plist file, the value here for `Label`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.chrisalvares.DLocationDemon.plist</string>
```

is not correct.  It shouldn't be `com.chrisalvares.DLocationDemon.plist`.  It should just be `com.chrisalvares.DLocationDemon`.  In many cases, it doesn't matter.  But, if you are issuing `launchctl stop` commands, the name for `Label` must match what you pass to launchctl.  If you repeated the mistake in the tutorial, then you either need to fix the plist file, or use this command:

```c
system("launchctl stop com.test.myDaemon.plist");
```

4. Finally, there *might* be an issue with calling `exit(0)`.  First, it's possible that if you run this enough times, and call `exit(0)` enough times, iOS might flag your process as a badly behaving process, and refuse to continue to restart it.  I don't think these rules are documented anywhere, but there are other similar features in iOS that work this way.  So, that might suggest using `launchctl` instead.  The other thought I had is that, even though `exit(0);` worked *once* for me, it's possible that you should chose a different exit code (not 0).  I know that with VoIP apps (which are similar to a daemon in some ways), iOS only restarts your app automatically if it exits with a **non-zero** exit code.  So, you might try `exit(1);`.

Those are my best guesses.

### References

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it. Actually exit code was called enough times as you described in step 4.

Comment: @AhadKhan, I guess I don't understand.  If the problem is as I describe in #4, and iOS is not restarting your app after it calls `exit(0)` a number of times, then that's not the solution you should use.  When you accept an answer, you're telling other people who read the page which answer worked best for you.